# What is the approx value of $f(50001)/f(50000)$ where $f(i)$ gives the value of the $i$-th number in the Fibonacci series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

What is the approx value of $f(50001)/f(50000)$ where $f(i)$ gives the value of the $i$-th number in the Fibonacci series?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fibonacci%2850001%29%2Ffibonacci%2850000%29. What does that number remind you of? Hint: GR.

Comment: Hint: The apporximate value tends towards the positive solution to this equation: $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fibonacci numbers $f(n)$ are given by [the closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_numbers#Closed-form_expression) $$\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(A^n - B^n\right)$$

where $$A=\frac{1+\sqrt5 }2\hphantom{.}\\
B=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2.$$

For large $n$, the $B^n$ term is insignificant because $|B|<1$.  So for large $n$, we have $$f(n) \approx \frac1{\sqrt5}A^n$$

and therefore $$\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} \approx A = \frac{1+\sqrt5}2\approx 1.618.$$

Answer (score 2):

The ratio of consecutive terms of the Fibonacci sequence tends to $\phi$, the [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio).

There are several ways to see this. one is that the Fibonacci sequence follows the recursion
$$
f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}\tag{1}
$$
and the solutions to this [linear recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Fibonacci_numbers) are linear combinations of the two geometric solutions: $\phi^n$ and $(-1/\phi)^n$. These are solutions since they are roots of the related equation $x^2-x-1=0.$ In fact,
$$
f_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-1/\phi)^n}{\sqrt5}\tag{2}
$$
It is simple to show that the ratio of the terms of $(2)$ tend to $\phi$.